# How to display the image selection field from the media library in the OpenCart 3 module admin panel

Tags: php, html, opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

How to display the image selection field from the media library in the OpenCart 3 module admin panel? Tried it like a normal textbox but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lats say we need to add and image in Module Featured, for example.

Go to */admin/view/template/extension/module/featured.php*

Almost in any place inside of `public function index() { ... }` (might be after `$this->load->model('setting/module');` and before `$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module/featured', $data));`) add following.

I have add it before `if (isset($this->request->post['top'])) {`

```
if (isset($this->request->post['image'])) {
  $data['image'] = $this->request->post['image'];
} elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
  $data['image'] = $module_info['image'];
} else {
  $data['image'] = '';
}

$this->load->model('tool/image');

if (isset($this->request->post['image']) && is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $this->request->post['image'])) {
  $data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($this->request->post['image'], 100, 100);
} elseif (!empty($module_info) && is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $module_info['image'])) {
  $data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($module_info['image'], 100, 100);
} else {
  $data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.png', 100, 100);
}

$data['placeholder'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.png', 100, 100);
```

Than, in */admin/view/template/extension/module/featured.twig* find

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name">{{ entry_name }}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ name }}" placeholder="{{ entry_name }}" id="input-name" class="form-control" />
    {% if error_name %}
    <div class="text-danger">{{ error_name }}</div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

And add after

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ entry_image }}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10"><a href="" id="thumb-image" data-toggle="image" class="img-thumbnail"><img src="{{ thumb }}" alt="" title="" data-placeholder="{{ placeholder }}" /></a>
    <input type="hidden" name="image" value="{{ image }}" id="input-image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Now it should work.

Comment: in the first paragraph instead go to /admin/view/template/extension/module/featured.twig  need  /admin/controller/extension/module/featured.php Very good. Thanks